# what are best practices for showing help information

Tags: android

I would like to put fairly extensive help information within my app - both "how to use" and explanation of what one is seeing.

The app (map oriented) has a row of buttons at the bottom, and I was considering adding a help button.

Context sensitive help is mostly not appropriate, btw.

What are common and best practices for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest using a help button, once the user knows how to use your app it will be useless, and will only takes some space.

What I do (but it's maybe not the best practice) is to show a popup on the first use. Within the popup I put some basic help and a link to my website which fully explains how my app works (with some screenshots to make it user-friendly). I also put a "Help" button in the activity menu which redirects to my website again.

What I can suggest is to explore by yourself how other android apps shows the help information, and reuse or adapt the one you prefer (this is what I've done).

Answer (score 0):

I have put help into a menu item as I expect new users to click the menu button anyway (my app, Zwitscher also has a button bar at the bottom).

Clicking the menu item then starts an Activity that simply shows a table view that explains the various buttons in the system and contains a link to more information online.
See https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/HelpActivity.java and
https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/master/res/layout/help.xml

Answer (score 0):

Another option I've seen sometimes is including a help option in the preferences/configuration screen.

Usually it starts a new activity with a sequence of steps to make the user understand everything.